# URL params, using backbone.js

Tags: url, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have this kind of URL: 
 something.com/#page/id (structured with backbone.js)
 I want to check if that id exists and use it in DOM using underscore.js, i know I can do that with window.location.href.split, but I just want to know is there a more proper and cleaner way..

Answer (score 1):

```
"page/:id": "someFunction" #this will be your route and it should have a function.

# In that someFunction you can check parameter (id) as shown below.

someFunction: function (id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```